# CAShapeLayer subview not animating correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, calayer, cashapelayer

I am attempting to use CALayer for animations.  What I want is the circle to shrink and bounce back (which works) and a stroked circle to expand and fade out [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Fy8vD/).  Unfortunately the second ring on the subLayer doesnt animate.  I am not sure why.

I setup my layers like so

```
- (void)setLayerProperties {
    //The view’s Core Animation layer used for rendering.
    CAShapeLayer *layer = (CAShapeLayer *)self.layer;

    UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)
                                                      byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners
                                                            cornerRadii:self.frame.size];
    layer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
    layer.fillColor = _Color.CGColor;

    rippleLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init]; // update from Andrea's answer
    layer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
    layer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    [layer addSublayer:rippleLayer];
}
```

I then animate then using these functions

```
- (void)pop{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [self animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    [animation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];
    [animation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8f]];
    [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:YES];
    [animation setDuration:0.15];
    [animation setAutoreverses:YES];

    [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:animation.keyPath];

    rippleLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1);
    CABasicAnimation *scale = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    [scale setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];
    [scale setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0f]];
    [scale setRepeatCount:1];
    [scale setDuration:1.0f];
    //r[scale setRemovedOnCompletion:YES];
    [scale setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];

    [rippleLayer addAnimation:scale forKey:scale.keyPath];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are creating rippleLayer as a normal CALayer, not a CAShapeLayer. path is not a property of CALayer as far as I remember, and you are giving path to the same layer as before. So you are adding a simple layer with no content at all.

Comment: Interesting, it does display though! Ill try change it (ps nice avatar Heisenburg!) ---- I just changed it and it does the same thing: Displays the stroked circle but doesnt animate it `rippleLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];`

Comment: @Chris check the lines right after you create the rippleLayer...you are giving path to layer(again) and  the stroke color to layer(again), wouldn't you give them to rippleLayer? In this way ripple layer has not contents?